# Tkinter Combobox button size

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I need a BIG combobox, its for a touchscreen application. I've managed to get the drop-down list scaled up, the combobox taller, but the dropdown button is still the default width. How do I make it bigger?

Comment: have you tried using a large font? Have you tried using the geometry manager to stretch the widget to the preferred size?